# Using Worklight JSONStore

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am not that new to Worklight, but the JSONStore is a new feature and I'm trying to learn how to use it. I downloaded the sample app (module_07_10_Using_JSONStore.zip) and installed it in my development environment, ran build and deployed it.

When I preview the app (as Android) in the Mobile Browser Simulator, and run through the sequence of Initialize the Collection, Add a Document, and then try to Find by Name, Find All, or get Number of Documents in Collection - I do not see the table at the bottom of the screen that displays the input data. I don't see any errors in the WL console. In the Android console, I get the error messages: 
Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file - and then it points to location of jarlist.cache in the module.

I did not make any changes to the code. I looked it over, compared it to the education module content, and I don't see the problem. Any thoughts? Clues? Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated my Android API level so that fixed the error I was seeing, but the app itself still doesn't do anything. There are no other errors to go on. Anyone else get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSONStore is not supported in the Mobile Browser Simulator, it must run on an Android or iOS device or simulator, if you run it on the Android simulator it should work just fine.

Comment: Related thread: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14929598#14929598

Comment: Yes, I finally figured that out. Thanks!